# AWS VPC Multiple IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to associate a secondary internal IP with my Amazon VPC small machine, I am using a Ubuntu based image with AMI ID:ami-6936fb00.
Problem is that I am unable to figure out how to configure my OS(Ubuntu) to record the second private IP address ( this is required as mentioned in the AWS Docs: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#using-instance-addressing-eips)!

I have single ENI and have associated one extra private IP with it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about EC2? AWS [VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) is a completely different thing (more VPN/networkish stuff)

Comment: I believe Multiple IPs are possible in VPC only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` file probably has something like the following:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.0.2.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.2.1
```

This is what assigns the primary IP (it may also be DHCP). To assign a secondary IP add a post-up script to attach an additional address to eth0.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.0.2.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    up ip addr add 192.168.2.20/24 dev eth0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please tell me how is your solution better than mine, I am not a guru in networking and want to understand which approach is better.

Comment: @APZ Aliased interfaces (i.e. `eth0:0`) are a hack created by `ifconfig` in order to support multiple IP addresses. They are considered deprecated however, and iproute2 (i.e. the `ip` command) should be used instead to attach multiple IPs to a single interface, which is what my solution does.

Comment: @mgorven Could you please explain the "20/24" part? Also, I am trying to add 4 IP addresses to two ENI's (for a total of 8 IPs). I can do it in the Amazon Linux AMI no problem (since Amazon gives you instructions in their documentation), but do you think this approach would work for that? Thanks!

Comment: @jeffp The IP is 192.168.2.20; the /24 specifies the subnet mask, i.e. 24 bits make up the network part and 32-24=8 bits make up the host part. If you have a specific question you should [ask a question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask) though.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure out how to record second private IP for my AWS VPC machine:
I appended this to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 192.x.y.z
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and then running `ifup eth0:0`

My ifconfig showed both eth0 and eth0:0 with correct private IPs.